# Issue with Identity Service - Unable to login via Load Balancer

Tags: identity-server

I am facing an issue with Sitecore identity service.

We have hosted the service in a VM and assigned *localhost:81*. The same is mapped to *identity-company.com* via load balancer. The problem is, login works when I connect the directly to *localhost:81* from the server and shows the logged in user at the right top. When I access *identity-company.com*, page is loading fine but  nothing happens when I try to login, irrespective of the username and password matching, on submit the page just reloads. I tried to add a new hostname inside server and I could see the same result. As of now it is only working inside the server with the URL localhost:81

Is there anything I can do to fix the issue? Is there any additional steps I need to do add 2 hostnames for identity service?

The difference I could in the logs is when login localhost:81 there is an additional log entry `Authentication Scheme ""idsrv" signed in` which is not there in the logs for URL which doesn't work

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you are hosting an identity server, then you should have a valid certificate for the domain it is running under and be running it on https / port 443. Is identity-company.com being accessed via https if so how are you mapping through LB? Also what happens if you create a local host entry for the domain and access on the VM via identity-company.com